# Unable to get and set the RichTextBox.CaretPosition programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, richtextbox

I have tried several attempts for this, but nothing has worked so far.

Here is what I have for a normal TextBox (this works like a charm, but as I need to do some formatting I need it to work for the RichTextBox, too):

```
//this works:
//Save the actual CaretIndex for later
safeActualCaretPositionInTextBox = txtFormulaString.CaretIndex;
//Insert the (user-)chosen text by another control
txtFormulaString.Text = txtFormulaString.Text.Insert(txtFormulaString.CaretIndex, function.PlainFunction);
//set focus back to TextBox
txtFormulaString.Focus();
//set CaretIndex at needed position (as I insert some formula (i. e. COS()) I need the CaretIndex n position(s) to the left)
txtFormulaString.CaretIndex = safeActualCaretPositionInTextBox + function.PlainFunction.Length;
txtFormulaString.CaretIndex -= function.CaretOffset;
txtFormulaString.SelectionLength = 0;
```

I have tried this ([`RichTextBox.CaretPosition Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition?view=netcore-3.1)) and currently have this:

```
safeActualCaretPositionInRichTextBox = rtbFormulaString.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
rtbFormulaString.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward).InsertTextInRun(function.PlainFunction);
rtbFormulaString.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(-function.CaretOffset);
rtbFormulaString.Focus();
rtbFormulaString.CaretPosition = safeActualCaretPositionInRichTextBox;
```

The insertion seems to work but I can't set the caret to the right position. It always starts at the beginning of the text.
What do I do wrong or what am I missing?

EDIT:
As I use MVVM in my project, I have a property in my ViewModel which needs to be updated after every text change (RichTextBox_TextChanged event is used):

```
vm.FormulaString = new TextRange(rtbFormulaString.Document.ContentStart, rtbFormulaString.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```

When I delete this line, it works sometimes (I don't know why or how and I don't understand why it behaves like that).

Answer (score 0):

To make the caret move to the end of the text you just added programatically you can use the following code :

```
TextRange newText = new TextRange(yourRichTextBox.CaretPosition, yourRickTextBox.CaretPosition);
newText.Text = yourString;
yourRichTextBox.CaretPosition = newText.End;
```

It's pretty clear to understand : pickup the current position of your caret, write some text at it and then move the caret to the end of it

**EDIT :**

To save the position before inserting and to get the offset added by your new text you can use a method like this :

```
public static uint GetDistanceUntil(this TextPointer start, TextPointer end)
{
    uint ret = 0;
    TextPointer currentPosition = start;
    while (currentPosition.CompareTo(end) != 0)
    {
        // if currentPosition becomes null, you passed through the whole document that contains start and didn't find end 
        // (most likely because start and end aren't in the same document or because start was after end)
        currentPosition = currentPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Forward); 
        ret++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

To obtain the current position of your carret as a number : `yourRichTextBox.ContentStart.GetDistanceUntil(yourRichTextBox.CaretPosition);`

And to get the "length" of your text : `newText.Start.GetDistanceUntil(newText.End);`

Once you're done adding the text you can obtain the `TextPointer` where your caret should be by using the method that does the "conversion" the other way :

```
public static TextPointer MoveTo(this TextPointer start, uint distance)
{
    TextPointer ret = start;
    while (distance > 0)
    {
        // if ret becomes null, you passed through the whole document that contains start and didn't move enough yet according to given distance
        ret = ret.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Forward); 
        distance--;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And set the `CaretPosition` of your `RichTextBox` to `yourRichTextBox.ContentStart.MoveTo(savedPosition + textLength);`

I'm pretty sure you can adapt both methods if you don't always want to use `LogicalDirection.Forward`

Comment: Thank you, but I need the caret to be wherever I need it to be. That could be the end of the text, but it also can be somewhere in the middle of the text.

Comment: @LiliumCandidum How do you determine where it has to go?

Comment: I want to save the current position and reassign it after the insert (plus/minus the length/offset of the inserted text (see my example with the TextBox in my question)

Comment: I have a little trouble with the MoveTo function as there is no declaration for "currentPosition". I'm just trying to implement your answer and let you know if it has helped me.

Comment: Ah yeah gonna edit, i forgot to replace it with `ret` instead

Comment: The first time the insert is successful and the caret is in a new line (it shouldn't but I will find a way to avoid that) and every time after the first time the system crashes in the MoveTo function, because ret is null (That happens even when I move the caret manually to another position bevor inserting another text)